# excel variance and Standard deviation - how to type the formula in order can calculate in specific date range? from current date to 1 month ago,

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

How to type the formula in order can calculate in specific date range?

can auto calculate from current date to 1 month ago, 1 years , 3 years

Excel - for variance and standard deviation, any formula can do

for example - `=AVERAGEIFS(C24:C2107,A24:A2107,">="&B1(today()),A24:A2107,"<="&A1)`

but for variance and standard deviation, i m no idea how to do, anyone can teach me thanks

Comment: Have you considered a "helper" column that produces a 1 or a 0 according to the date to produce an array for stdev etc?

Comment: If you multiply by 1 what do you get? Multiply by 0... then use stdev on the values that remain... not a challenging formula ... Not a good idea to post your email address...

Comment: ok  thanks for ur advice, i will delete it , ohh u mean just another column, if 0 nth u will get, if multiple 1 * 30 date become monthly, column 1, 0 is very helpful , but if i update the data again, but really dont have any formula can show latest from current monthly, yearly , 1 and 0 column i need adjust everytimes once i key in new date, any formula can like formula - AVERAGEIFS Today() - 30 days ago, haha it will more convenient rite,